# How to create my own reporting controls with .net framework?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, reporting, report

I want to create fast loading reports like ActiveReports or DevExpress but the problem is I don't know where to start. Also I want it to be light and take less space in setup file.

Does anybody tried to do this? Can I write this component with .net?

This must not be so hard?

Comment: The speed of the reports is often related to the speed of the query that runs behind to populate the data.  If the data pull is complex, it doesn't matter how well your report items are coded, they will have to wait for the data.

Comment: Sure you're right. I'll recheck my sql queries :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by looking here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/rdlproject.aspx

It's an open source version of implemented Report Definition Language.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the one that [ships with VS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671%28VS.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, also I've used Crystal Reports before (which was very slow) but I need fast and light reporting which supports editing by client.

Comment: What is 'slow'? What is 'fast and light'? You have to be a bit more clear. Depending on the complexitity of your reports I would suggest CrystalReports, easy to maintain and create reports. Never had a problem with 'slowness'. It takes a couple of seconds to create a report but thats obvious with a lot of rows and complex formula's. Please update the question what you want to achieve, simpe listing of records or records with complex select formulas.

Comment: Yes I also meant that Crystal Reports loads slow. But everything else is okay with CR (Exporting, Paging etc).
I need reporting for my shop sales organizer. Usually used by mini markets where computers are slow and old. I need reporting for sale details. A report can have approximately 2k rows * 5 cols. Data is text. No images or complex calculations except sum of the total sale amount.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in doing this in WPF, you might check out "Practical WPF Charts and Graphics"

[http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Charts-Graphics-Experts-Voice/dp/1430224819/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224819)

Answer (score 1):

> fast loading reports

You might consider techniques such as pre-processing the data, and caching. That can decouple the rendering time from the computational time.